Huggingface space in javascript with gradio-lite
I want to implement huggingface text-to-image space in javascript without node.js with gradio-lite but when I try this, I get error, you can read documentation and please give me only example of js code for any good huggingface text-to-image space with part for entering prompt and button and part for generating image with gradio-lite!
